# C or C++ for cross-platform mobile development?

Tags: android, c++, ios

For a cross-platform project on iOS, Android and Windows I originally wrote some underlying classes in C++. From what I understand however, I will have to write an objective-C wrapper to allow the swift iPhone project to work in xcode. Would it make more sense then that I simply rewrite all of the original framework in C or would simply wrapping it in C be a better solution. No problem either way just attempting to determine the best way to keep the code valid.

Also telling me to use a cross-platform mobile development SDK is not helpful.

Comment: C is usually less of a pain, when targeting multiple (unrelated) platforms, using multiple different toolchains and runtime libraries. Even though C++ support is somewhat mature for all 3 platforms, you'll still run into subtle differences and intricacies particularly with the newer features (threads, etc.). I'd still recommend against rewriting everything from scratch, rather than wrapping your C++ code behind a C interface. But this question is fairly opinion-based, and may be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend writing in C++ 11. It's more modern, has more support online, and you can even compile everything with Cmake. There are many tools out there to help you with this. My company is using this to develop a framework that compiles on the following platforms:

iOS, Mac OS X, Android (ARM, x86, x64), Windows (x86, x64), Linux (x86, x64)

You can also find a tool here to help you with cross platform toolchains, so that code you compile is easily ready for multiple platforms: https://github.com/ruslo/polly